# Sorting the list while using iterator

Tags: java, sorting

I need to sort my list of objects **by the row number first then the column number**. Whenever a user `set(row, col, x)`, it is put into the `rowColSeq` in a certain position. For example,

```
board.set(1, 1, "aa");
board.set(1, 3, "aa");
board.set(0, 1, "B");
board.set(0, 2, "B");
board.set(1, 0, "aa");
```

The list should be sorted in the following manner:

```
[0,1,"B"], [0,2,"B"], [1,0,"aa"], [1,1,"aa"], [1,3,"aa"]
```

But my code is giving me infinite loop. Could smb tell me what I did worng with my code?

**Assume the list is NOT empty!**

```
  LinkedList<RowColElem<T>> rowColElems; //contains some info

 private void sortedRowColSeq(int row, int col, T x){
      RowColElem<T> object = new RowColElem<T>(row, col, x);
      ListIterator<RowColElem<T>> iter = rowColSeq.listIterator();
      while(iter.hasNext()){
          RowColElem<T> inListObject = iter.next();
          if(object.getRow() < inListObject.getRow()){
              iter.previous();
              iter.add(object);
          }
          else if(object.getRow() == inListObject.getRow()){
              if(object.getCol() < inListObject.getCol()){
                  iter.previous();
                  iter.add(object);
              }
              else{
                  iter.add(object);
              }
          }
          else{
              iter.add(object);
          }
      }
  }
```

**`RowColElem<T>` class**

```
public class RowColElem<T>{
  private int row;
  private int col;
  private T elem;

  // Create a RowColElem with the parameter parts
  public RowColElem(int r, int c, T e){
    this.row = r;
    this.col = c;
    this.elem = e;
  }

  // Return the row
  public int getRow(){
    return this.row;
  }

  // Return the column
  public int getCol(){
    return this.col;
  }

  // Return the element
  public T getElem(){
    return this.elem;
  }

  // Return a pretty string version of the triple formated as
  // (row,col,elem)
  public String toString(){
    return String.format("(%d,%d,%s)",row,col,elem);
  }

  @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
  // Perform a deep equality check between this RowColElem and another
  // object
  public boolean equals(Object other){
    if(other == null || !(other instanceof RowColElem)){
      return false;
    }
    RowColElem<T> that = (RowColElem<T>) other;
    return
      this.row == that.row &&
      this.col == that.col &&
      this.elem.equals(that.elem);
  }
}
```

Comment: What sorting algorithm are you trying to use? Because it doesn't seem too efficient. Why are `sortedRowColSeq` taking parameters? What is `rowColSeq`? However, a more important question is that why don't you use `Arrays.sort` or `Collections.sort` and implement a`Comparator` for your custom type `RowColElem`?

Comment: *"But my code is giving me infinite loop"* I wonder why ... maybe because you always add more stuff to the iterator, so it has not chance to ever reach the final element?

Comment: @CMate, I cannot use comparator at all! I have to only use the iterator.

Comment: @Tom, how to stop  the loop ?

Comment: @KemalP. If it is a homework task, you may look up sorting algorithms. Bubble sort or insertion sort are quite easy to implement, although they have an `O(n^2)` complexity. Quick sort is a bit harder, but has an `O(n*log n)` average complexity.

You are trying to implement bubble sort as I am guessing by your code :), but as @Tom mentioned, you are only adding elements to the collection, never removing one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All I can say, is that a `.hasNext` with a code like yours is giving the infinite loop. You put a new elem everytime no matter what. You should have a condition that does not create a race situation. You're code adds beyond the one it has in hand, and that's the race condition.

Comment: I added `break` after each statement but it sorts incorrectly:`[(0,1,B), (1,0,aa), (0,2,B), (1,1,aa), (1,3,aa)]`, @DavidPulse

Comment: Honestly, you're not properly sorting. Real sorting uses a temp var to hold while you change with the other variable the original value. And it gets halved in iterations each time.

Comment: The algorithm doesn't really sort, it just puts the object between its predecessor and successor in terms of row and col indexing, @DavidPulse. I'd appreciate it if you helped me with this algorithm

Comment: You need to take out that your last else. You're looking at a race condition there. Your program aims at node 1, then runs through, and no matter what, according to your code, you're using `.add`. This means there is always a next, because you created it while looking at node n. You create a race condition by making it chase forever. You see that n+1 is created each time?

Answer (score 3):

Your basic problem is that you wrote sorting code. The solution is a one liner:

```
Collections.sort(Comparators.comparing(RowColElem::getRow)
  .andThen(RowColElem::getCol));
```

Comment: Thank you! But Im not allowed to use Collections.sort() at all. @Bohemian♦

Comment: @kemal your question doesn't say that.. Probably the easiest sort to implement is an in-place insertion sort: starting at index 0, find the smallest element in the list (including the current index) and swap it with current index, then increment index and repeat until whole list has been processed.

Comment: That's the only algorithm that I have to use for this project, @Bohemian♦, the only problem is it's running infinitly. How could I stop that?